# C# - чтение данных с HID-клавиатуры

Tags: c#, usb, клавиатура

Имеется HID-клавиатура (на пульте ДУ).
Требуется определять, какие HID-коды она посылает на USB-порт.
Прошу объяснить, как это можно сделать или хотя бы подсказать готовые решения и библиотеки для решения подобной задачи.

Comment: USBPcap + Wireshark покажут что посылается.

Comment: просто посмотреть - https://docklight.de/download/Docklight_Scripting.zip ,    написать самому - https://github.com/signal11/hidapi